# Wouldn't training the model with this data lead to inaccuracies since the testing data would not be normalized in a similar way?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, keras, test-datasets, standardisation

I was trying to normalize my input data images for feeding to my convolutional neural network and wanted to use standardize my input data.

I referred to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57200621/3924118), which says that `featurewise_center` and `featurewise_std_normalization` scale the images to the range `[-1, 1]`.

Wouldn't training the model with this data lead to inaccuracies since the testing data would not be normalized in a similar way and would only range between `[0, 1]`? How can I standardize my data while keeping its range between `[0, 1]`?